# C# Line delimited Textfile to DataGrid Cells

Tags: c#, arrays, datagrid, text-files

I'm building a WinForm app for my filmmaking business that I will use to input all of my available talent's information. After inputting each talent's information and clicking the "Add Record" button, the textboxes will all be added to a datagrid and a text file. I am adding the information like so:

```
    public void AddToActorFile()
    {
        List<string> actorList = new List<string>();
        actorList.Add(midianTalent.Name);
        actorList.Add(midianActor.CharacterName);
        actorList.Add(midianActor.CastHeight);
        actorList.Add(midianActor.CastWeight);
        actorList.Add(midianActor.CastAge);
        actorList.Add(midianActor.CastSSN);
        actorList.Add(imageFileName);
        // B.
        string[] actorArray = actorList.ToArray();
        File.AppendAllLines(@"Cast.txt", actorArray);

        MessageBox.Show(cbPosition.SelectedItem + " Added to Cast File");
        AddActorToDataGrid();
    }

    public void AddActorToDataGrid()
    {
        actorDataGrid.Rows.Add(midianTalent.Name, midianActor.CastAge, midianActor.CastHeight, midianActor.CastWeight, midianActor.CastSSN, imageFileName);

    }
```

The textfile ends up line delimited so it reads like this

```
Actor1Info1
Actor1Info2
Actor1Info3
Actor1Info4
Actor1Info5
Actor1Info6
Actor2Info1
Actor2Info2
Actor2Info3
```

and so on . . . so each actor has 6 fields that get written one right after another

I then want to close the app and when I reopen it, have the textfile automatically populate the datagrid with each actor's information. The datagrid has 6 columns, each row is 1 actor and each column holds the relevant information.

All the above works correctly, except I can't figure out the reading of the textfile. I am using the following method

```
     public void ReadTalentFileData()
    {
        using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader("Talent.txt"))
        {
            int column = 0;
            string fileLine;
            while ((fileLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] cells = fileLine.Split('\n');
                talentDataGrid.Rows.Add();
                for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
                {
                    talentDataGrid[column, i].Value = cells[i];
                }
                column++;

            }
        }
    }
```

The first actor lists fine, but no matter how many actors I put in there, that is the only record that shows up, I also have extra rows in my datagrid that are blank. Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong in my readfile method so that each actor shows up in the datagrid.

I also welcome tips on refactoring the code.

I will eventually change this to read and write from my online MySQL database because I will have each one of my actors use this app, but I want to get this local copy working so I can put each talent's information in there. I will then export the textfile to the database, make the changes I need for the database and then release the app to my talent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join the lines into comma separated values instead of 6 lines per actor.

```
var line = string.Join(",",  actorList);
```

Next you can read the file simply since each line is an actor.

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("Talent.txt"))
{
    var columns = line.Split(',');
    talentDataGrid.Rows.Add(columns)
}
```

Comment: using your suggestion on using the Join, I now have it creating a comma delimited list in the text file, but since I'm not binding a source to the datagrid, the reading won't work . . . but now that I have it to a comma delimited list, I can easily read the file using one of the many examples I have found on the internet.

I just couldn't find many that dealt with a line delimited list or showed how to convert it to comma delimited . . . Thanks

Comment: Ah. You can just use the `columns` which is a string array and assign each index to the corresponding column. I'll throw in an edit.